# how to download an attachment in browser?

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API in browser and want to allow the user to download email attachments. I see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get but it returns JSON and base64 data. I don't think I can get that data in memory then trigger a "download" to save the file locally. Even if I could I don't think it would be efficient - it would probably download the file in memory vs. streaming it to a file. I think I need a direct link to a file that returns the correct file name and raw binary data (not base64). Is there a way to do this? Right now the only way I see is to proxy requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the base64 and save it to file locally.

If you are getting the attachment in Java, you can use the `FileOutputStream` class `(or f.write() in Python)` to write the bytes to file and save it locally with a path.

You can try with the following sample code from Google Developer page:

```
public static void getAttachments(Gmail service, String userId, String messageId)
      throws IOException {
    Message message = service.users().messages().get(userId, messageId).execute();
    List<MessagePart> parts = message.getPayload().getParts();
    for (MessagePart part : parts) {
      if (part.getFilename() != null && part.getFilename().length() > 0) {
        String filename = part.getFilename();
        String attId = part.getBody().getAttachmentId();
        MessagePartBody attachPart = service.users().messages().attachment().
            get(userId, messageId, attId).execute();
        byte[] fileByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(attachPart.getData());
        FileOutputStream fileOutFile =
            new FileOutputStream("directory_to_store_attachments" + filename);
        fileOutFile.write(fileByteArray);
        fileOutFile.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm talking about in a browser client side so have to be able to do it in javascript with browser restrictions.